# What does the field vuln-security-protection stand-for in the NVD cve lists 2.0?

Tags: cve, nist, vulnerability

In the different NVD files which enumerates the CVE, which can be found [here](http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm)

There is from time to time the field `<vuln:security-protection>`
, containing often the value `ALLOWS_OTHER_ACCESS` or `ALLOWS_ADMIN_ACCESS`.

Do you know what this field stand for ? What does it means ?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://nvd.nist.gov/faq.cfm#assignimpacttypes) FAQ about assigning vulnerability types implies that `<vuln:security-protection>` indicates that a vulnerability can be leveraged to gain access to a system.

Access is the holy grail when trying to compromise a system since if you have access you can then compromise the system in any other way you want (availability, integrity, confidentiality).

The presence of the `<vuln:security-protection>` element indicates that the vulnerability impacts on access rights while the value (`ALLOWS_ADMIN_ACCESS` etc.) indicates the level of impact.